# How do I call this method without getting C2227 error?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm programming a Qt application in C++11 and I'm learning as I go, so this is probably a question with a really obvious answer. I've got an application that fills a graphics scene in the mainwindow with thumbnails (picts) that the user can select multiple of. I'm trying to implement functionality that when a user clicks on one, the previous selection is cleared. Since mouse click events occur on the pict object, I'm trying to get it to tell the whole window to deselect the rest.

Here's the main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;

    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

here's an excerpt of mainwindow.cpp:

```
vector<Pict*> PictArray;  
vector<int> ActiveList;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    int viewwidth = ui->graphicsView->width();

    //test values
    int moment = 0;
    nitems = 47; 

    int maxitems_x = viewwidth/72; 
    int maxitems = 1000;
    if(nitems > maxitems){nitems = maxitems;}

    PictArray.resize(nitems);

    //fill the scene
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while(true){
        PictArray[k] = new Pict(moment, k);         
        PictArray[k]->setPos(QPointF(i*72, j*72 + 16));        
        scene->addItem(PictArray[k]);
        i++;
        k++;
        if(i == maxitems_x){i=0; j++;}
        if(k == nitems){break;}
    }

    qDebug() << "Drew" << nitems << "items" ;

    //test select some objects

    array<int, 4> v0_init = {3, 6, 9, 12};  //can't use list constructors with MSVC12)
    vector<int> v0(v0_init.begin(), v0_init.end());
    selectPicts(v0);
}

.
.
.

void MainWindow::deselectAllPicts()
{
    for(auto& i : ActiveList)
    {
        PictArray[i]->setSelected(false);
    }
    ActiveList.clear();
}
```

and then from the pict object, this method:

```
void Pict::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{   
    window->deselectAllPicts();
    qDebug() << "selected: set " << this->s << " img " << this->n;
    this->color.setRed((qrand() % 256 + 255)/2);        //test: on click, set border to a random color
    this->color.setGreen((qrand() % 256  + 255)/2);
    this->color.setBlue((qrand() % 256 + 255)/2);
    this->isactive = true;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

but I get error C2227 ("->deselectAllPicts must point to a class/struct/union/generic type"). How do I go about fixing this? The author admits he was never any good at OOP, so I appreciate any help.

(I don't plan on leaving this all on Mainwindow - I'm going to make the scene into a custom object when I start adding more stuff than just this to the window)

Comment: Is `window` a data member of `Pict`? And there's no need to qualify every member access with `this->`

Comment: How is `window` defined? Basically the error says that what is left of `->deselectAllPicts` must be some kind of object, that has named properties (not sure if the wording is most apropriate) that can be accessed and it seems it is not.

Comment: "window" is the Mainwindow object defined in main

Comment: @Bamako, yes, but `window` it is in the scope of `main()` and is not accesible from the class, you should pass it as parameter or something.

Comment: I don't use VS, but its quite puzzling why it doesn't complain that `window` is not defined at all within the `Pict::mousePressEvent` scope, over not being a good type for accessing a member.

Comment: I don't think I can overload that event, since that's how mousepressevent is defined

Comment: @Bamako Noone wants you to overload anything. You need to give the notion of what `window` is in the `Pict::mousePressEvent` scope. In other words `Pict::mousePressEvent` needs to know what `window` is. Currently it does not, or at least its not a class that you say it should be. You should tell how `Pict` is related to `MainWindow` and then ask how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you reimplemented `QGraphicsItem` in your `Pict` class, you can add an extra argument to `Pict` constructor and pass your window to it:

```
PictArray[k] = new Pict(moment, k, this); // this in MainWindow refers to window itself
```

Store this window pointer in `Pict` constructor:

```
Pict::Pict(int moment, int k, MainWindow *window) : mainWindow(window), ... {...}
```

And then access the main window from `Pict`:

```
mainWindow->deselectAllPicts();
```

**Edit.**  P.S. you can simply select / deselect / get a list of selected items with `QGraphicsScene` mechanism. Have a look at `QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea()` and related methods.