# Qt Listwidget Item add

Tags: c++, qt

i tried to add an item of a listWidget in Qt, but it won't work.
The compiler is print out some errors, looking like that:

Fehler: C2039: 'listWidget': Ist kein Element von 'MainWindow'
Fehler: C2065: 'listWidget': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
Fehler: C2227: Links von "->addItem" muss sich ein Zeiger auf Klassen-/Struktur-/Union-/generischen Typ befinden.Typ ist ''unknown-type''

The code line:

```
MainWindow::listWidget->addItem("TEST");
```

Where's the misstake?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Q: Do you have a member "listWidget" in your class "MainWindow"?  Is it's Qt Type fully defined at that point in your source file?  Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004477/how-do-i-call-this-method-without-getting-c2227-error

Comment: The name, with it you can name a widget is the object name, right?

Comment: The specific error is `C2227: ->addItem must point to a class/struct/union/generic type`.   It's a C++ compile error; nothing to do with Qt per se.  Look at the similar "deselectAllPicts" error in the link I cited.  I believe it's the same basic problem - with the same solution.  IMHO...

Comment: Try `ui->listWidget->addItem("TEST");` if you added the widget from Designer and trying to access from within the `MainWindow` class.

Comment: i tested it with both options, but nothing work: ui-> :
 Fehler: C2065: 'ui': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner

and with MainWindow->listWidget (...):
Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ';' vor '->'

Comment: All right, the mistake caused by a defective project.
Thank you for help.